# Podman using all disk space

Tags: disk-space-utilization, podman, rhel9

I am running AlmaLinux 9 (RHEL 9 clone), and am new to podman.  I have been running my first and only container for a month, and today my disk is full:

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G  116K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.6G  180M  1.4G  12% /run
/dev/sda3        70G   70G  340K 100% /
tmpfs           3.9G  124K  3.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda2      1014M  606M  409M  60% /boot
/dev/sda1       599M  9.5M  590M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1       252G  138G  102G  58% /data
/dev/sda4        49G  379M   49G   1% /home
shm              63M     0   63M   0% /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay-containers/aca8a5a216ea6cdacc27cac48aa7ba8da880534d7bd332b626a5a3cef7e85c57/userdata/shm
overlay          70G   70G  340K 100% /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/7f2b2ecfa10f91b674069fafa26dfe18066f7d2e38d1e4f5001a47b21989d4bf/merged
tmpfs           795M   32K  795M   1% /run/user/0
```

It appears that my podman container has grown to fill the disk.  Why?  (I assume this is not normal).

Should I be scheduling a cron job to clean something up?  I found this command on another post:

```
docker system prune --all --volumes
```

but it only freed 1.5GB so there must be something else going on.

Comment: You seem to be intermixing the term docker and podman, those are two competing tools (though podman competes by impersonating docker). Please select a single tool since the advice may be specific to docker or podman.

Comment: I wasn't sure if docker was a wrapper around docker or an alternative - thanks for the fix.  I wonder if it's worth keeping the docker tag since I suspect the solution applies to both.

Comment: Check the sizes of your container volumes. Also check inside your container where the files actually are that acclaim the space. Clean that up.

Comment: I've cleaned everything up, still all space used.  I ended up enlarging the partition so my system is running again, but I fear podman's overlay will just keep eating up space.  Still hoping for a solution

Comment: What solution do you expect? You need to find out why the volume is filling up. To do that you need to analyze the used space inside that volume. Could be data, could be logs, could be anything. Nobody but you can do that.